# writing pandas dataframe to hdf5 using pytables module

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

in below example, i am trying to store a multiindex `pandas.DataFrame`in `h5` file format

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
store = pd.HDFStore('c:/temp/example.h5')
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['first']*3,['one','two','three']], names = ['outer','inner'])
abc = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,9).reshape(-1,3), index = idx, columns = list('abc'))
```

if i try to store the above dataframe ('abc') to store, i get an error, as below

```
store.put('abc',abc,format='t',append=True)
TypeError: shape must be an integer or sequence: 3L
```

i did not get this error before, maybe is could be related to version update for pytable. I am currently using version 3.2.2. Any pointer on what could be alternative solution to store the dataframe in h5 format?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use the [`to_hdf` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html)?

```
abc.to_hdf('c:/temp/example.h5')
```

Comment: i still get the same error, even with the alternative you propose. My guess is that under the hood, both methods are the same.